# Javascript- Multiple icon-minus signs displayed to minimise rows when single sign preferable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using some javascript I adapted from elsewhere to allow the user to add additional rows to a form. 
I'm using these functions to add and remove fields:

```
function addTrack(){

    var node = document.getElementById("fruitTable");
    var trs = node.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var tr = trs[trs.length-2];
    var tr2 = tr.cloneNode(true);
    tr.parentNode.insertBefore(tr2, tr);

    function plusone(str){
        return str.replace(
            new RegExp("-(\\d+)-", "gi"),
            function($0, $1){
                var i = parseInt($1) + 1;
                return "-" + i + "-";
            }
        );
    }

    var inputs = tr.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
        inputs[i].setAttribute("id", plusone(inputs[i].getAttribute("id")));
    }

    var minusbutton =
        ['<td>',
        '<button class="btn" type="button" onClick="removeTrack()"><i class="icon-black icon-minus"></i></button>',
        '</td>'
        ].join('\n');

    if (trs.length < 6){
        tr.innerHTML += minusbutton
    }
}

function removeTrack(){
    var node = document.getElementById("fruitTable");
    var trs = node.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var tr = trs[trs.length-2];
    var trParent = tr.parentNode;
    trParent.removeChild(tr);
}
```

Before the plus sign is pressed this is how the section of the form looks (I am happy at this point):

[image]

Once the button is pressed, the form looks like this (again, I am I am happy with the single minus icon at this point):

[image]

However, if more rows are added the form displays two minus icons next to each new row where I would prefer a single icon (see below). I can't tell from my function why this is happening?
As a side issue, I can't seem to get rid of the narrow white bordering lines above some of the elements. I've changed all table borders to Grey (the same shade as the background) but this doesn't seem to have gotten rid of them.

[image]

[image]

Here is the html from the template:

```
<table id="fruitTable" class="table">
    <tr><th>Items Description</th></tr>
    {% set counter = 0 %}
    {% for track in form1.item_description %}
    <tr>
        {{ track.hidden_tag() }}
        {% set counter = counter + 1%}
        {% for field in track if field.widget.input_type != 'hidden' %}
          {{ render_field_oneline(field) }}
        {% endfor %}
        {% if counter > 1 %}
          <td>
            <button class="btn" type="button" onClick="removeTrack()"><i class="icon-black icon-minus"></i></button>
          </td>
        {% endif  %}
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
      <tr><td></td><td><button class="btn" type="button" onClick="addTrack()"><i class="icon-black icon-plus"></i></button></td></tr>
  </table>

<table>
```

Here is a macro and addional css which I placed in a base.html file:

```
{% macro render_field_oneline(field) %}
<td>{{ field.label }}</td>
<td>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
  {% if field.errors %}
  <ul class=errors>
    {% for error in field.errors %}
    <li>{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  {% endif %}
</td>
{% endmacro %}

{% macro render_field(field) %}
<tr>
  {{ render_field_oneline(field) }}
</tr>
{% endmacro %}

<style>
{
        background-color: #A9A9A9;
}
table, tr, th, td {
    border: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please update your question with the appropriate HTML and CSS so that we can have a version of your code that is executable.

Comment: This is definitely a CSS issue. Providing a jsfiddle or something would help :/

Comment: @Josh Please don't ask for code to be posted to 3rd party sites as those links can become dead over time. Code should be posted right here in a code snippet.

Comment: I've added the extra info requested, thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the minusbutton, examine this part if your code:

```
if (trs.length < 6){
    tr.innerHTML += minusbutton
}
```

So, if you only need one minusbutton to be displayed next to each bar, you need to add a new  element to create a new row.

```
if ( trs.length < 6 ) {
    tr.innerHTML += minusbutton + '<tr><td></td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply John, this hasn't worked though.

Comment: How would you want the minusbutton to be displayed.

Comment: Just one next to each row rather than two.